# Can't install Deepin Software Center.deb

Tags: 12.04, installation, dpkg

I have been putting in the command `sudo dpkg -i package_file.deb` and it just says that there is no file.

Comment: Can't you just click it..

Answer (score 4):

You have downloaded the deb file in a directory but running this command in a different directory. The easiest way to install  this software is just double click the deb file.

And the precise answer to this question is go to the directory where you downloaded the deb file. Say you have downloaded in /home/Heavyonion/Downloads

```
cd /home/Heavyonion/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i package_file.deb
```

Or

```
sudo dpkg -i /home/Heavyonion/Downloads/package_file.deb
```

You can always check if a file exists or not by

```
ls /home/Heavyonion/Downloads/package_file.deb
```

Check this - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/01/how-to-run-the-linux-deepin-software-centre-in-ubuntu/

Comment: ok that worked but it said that errors were encountered while processing.

Comment: see my updated answer , if you still find issues, paste the error here

Answer (score 0):

But why are you using `sudo dpkg -i package_file.deb`. I think you are not providing the right name of the package. The error comes because there is no file named `package_file.deb`.
You should look what is the name of the package_file and use that name in the command. 
Suppose the name of the file you are trying to install is `deepin_software_center_i386.deb` then the command will be

`sudo dpkg -i deepin_software_center_i386.deb`

Else suppose you want to install all the deb files in single directory then cd to that directory and enter this command
`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. dpkg will install all the deb files in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Open the software centre and search for gdebi package manager ,
and press install button

then right click on the  .deb file and chose open with gdebi package manager

press install button on the new window ,

installation completed